# Name of vector $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$

Tags: terminology

Is there a name generally accepted for vectors of the form $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)\in \Bbb R^n$?

I understand this is one of the members of the orthonormal base of $\Bbb R^n$, but I believe that in the context I'm using. it this characterisation would be somewhat pedantic.

Also, is there a standard symbol to denote it? I was thinking of using $\mathbf{1}_{i^{*}}$, where $i^{*}$ stands for the position of the $1$.

Comment: $e_k$ is a popular designation for the $k$-th of these "basis vectors".

Comment: @AnginaSeng:  I would make that an answer.  In fact, I was just about to write it.

Comment: This is a vector of the canonical basis $C=\{e_1,e_2, \dots ,e_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{K^n}$. The vector $e_j$ has only the $j$-th component non zero, which is $1$.

Comment: I would call the vector with the $k$th entry a $1$ and all other entries $0$ the $k$th standard basis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, denoted $e_k$.

Comment: As an aside, you wrote "*this is one of the members of* **the** *orthonormal base of $\Bbb R^n$.*"  The English article "the" carries with it a connotation that what it describes is the only of its description.  There are many orthonormal bases possible for $\Bbb R^n$.  The one you are thinking of just happens to be the most standard.